# how do i read n any character from file?

Tags: c#

how do i read any n character from file with c# whole encoding?
i mean not reading byte! i wanna just read one character (any encoding) at a time?

Comment: If you don't know how your text is encoded in the file, you won't be able to read a character from it: The encoding defines how specific characters are to be read from a byte stream. You could even invent your own encoding if the existing one didn't suit your need. The consequence is plain simple: If you don't know how to read something, you can't read it. You must make assumptions about your content to be able to use it.

Comment: In order to read a character from a file, you first need to know what encoding it is.

Comment: Is this character produced by the any key?

Comment: if i knew which encoding also, i can' t read by character by character in way.because every character has a different bytes in UTF8.

Comment: if file contains those characters "abcçdefgğ_aaabbb_û»ø½ù¯þ¸²²^¬©¡®B7T;@R콓". i wanna read last 4 characters from file. how can i read?

Answer (score 3):

Use `TextReader.Read()`, probably via `StreamReader`, which inherits from `TextReader`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
char[] c = new char[5];
using (StreamReader streamReader = File.OpenText("c:\test.txt"))
{
    streamReader.Read(c, 0, c.Length);
}
```

**Update**:

I just realized that this is for UTF8 encoding only and no further parameters are available to specify the encoding.

Comment: Do not waste your time trying this.

Comment: try this characters "abcçdefgğ_aaabbb_û»ø½ù¯þ¸²²^¬©¡®B7T;@R콓" i wanna read last 4 characters from file

Answer (score -2):

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("date.txt");
string txt = reader.ReadToEnd();
txt(char num);
```

It's not the most efficient but neither is c# so :/

Comment: ty but in the large file it is not efficient. for example i want to read last 4 character from a large file... how can i do this?

Comment: I think you need to use file streams which involve some knowledge of bytes